# How to schedule automatically clean the temporary files on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, temporary-files

After a few months of usage my PC and laptop slows down. Then I use the utility called [CCleaner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCleaner) and then everything seems fast again.

Is there a utility which automatically clean the temporary and other waste files software or Windows create upon usage? So that my pc and laptop always remain fast.

Comment: You can schedule CCleaner using a Scheduled Task. Just configure CCleaner to automatically when launch clean the temporary file directory.  This has also already been asked http://superuser.com/questions/211574/automatically-deleting-c-documents-and-settings-user-local-settings-temp?rq=1

Comment: I want it to do the background clean, not to pop up in front of my face

Comment: The professional version of CCleaner can handle that.  Just start CCleaner automatically when Windows starts and let it handle the task automatically.

Comment: You mean in the background?

Comment: Would not have suggested that solution if it wasn't in the background or in the system tray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCleaner doesn't pop up in your face when it is doing an automatic clean, all it does is create a small flashing icon in the tray.

You can schedule an automatic clean by setting up what you want cleaned in CCleaner first, then a scheduled task running the command `"C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe" /AUTO`. This silently cleans the PC in the background.

You can of course have CCleaner run at scheduled intervals, at startup, shutdown, or logoff.

There are more command line parameter options on [Piriform's website](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters). The free version of CCleaner has this feature, as well as the Technician's edition.

If one would prefer to clean their temporary files without using a third party tool, see [magicandre1981's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/638360/201262).

Comment: Is it available in free version

Comment: Yes it is. Just tested it. I updated my answer to include the full command, you'd have to include the path to `ccleaner.exe`

Answer (score 6):

To clean the Temporary Internet files of the IE, download [this tool](http://www.wintecnico.com/ficheros/CleanIETempFiles.zip), expand it and open the Task Scheduler MMC snapin (taskschd.msc). Create a new scheduled task which runs weekly for example and select the expanded `CleanIETempFiles.exe`. At the textbox "Add arguments" enter `-t` and click ok.

Now the task scheduler kills the temporary files weekly.

To kill other files you can [automate the disk cleanup wizard](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10705/how-to-schedule-disk-cleanup-in-windows-7-vista/) (`cleanmgr.exe`) which is included in Windows. Run `cleanmgr.exe /sageset:1` and configure which files you want to clean. Go to the first created task, add a new program you want to run and select cleanmgr.exe as program and `/sagerun:1` to the arguments box.

[image]

This kills all temporary files without buying/using a 3rd party tool.

Comment: how to check, that this rule is saved? 
if again run the `cleanmgr /sageset:1` it shows default values.

Comment: @Psychozoic for me it works for years. try to run cleanmgr as admin.

Comment: Official explanation of the cleanmgr options and usage with the scheduler is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/automating-disk-cleanup-tool